# Converting ANSI to UTF-8 with Python Script in Notepad++ - unicode name issues

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, notepad++, ansi

I am using this script that was written by [Jun Murakami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/415555/jun-murakami) to convert the encode of .srt files (movie subtitles) from ANSI to UTF-8 and it is doing great and works perfect for me but there is problem. I have folders which have Unicode characters in their names and the script doesn't open .srt files in these folders. and i just want the script to  open these folders like others.

This is the script:

```
import os;
import sys;
filePathSrc="C:\\Users\\New folder\\" # Path to the folder with files to convert
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(filePathSrc):
for fn in files: 
    if fn[-4:] == '.srt': # Specify type of the files
        notepad.open(root + "\\" + fn)      
        notepad.runMenuCommand("Encoding", "Convert to UTF-8")
        notepad.save()
        notepad.close()
```

So i was wondering if anyone could help to solve this problem for me. Especially [Jun Murakami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/415555/jun-murakami) who wrote it at first or any of you guys who knows how to fix this. I will be so grateful.

Comment: What’s `notepad`? The object isn’t declared in your code. I’m assuming it’s an API to interoperate with Notepad++? — Anyway, why the detour via Notepad++? Python has more direct ways of working with text files.

Comment: Can u help me? @jun-murakami

Comment: @FarhadMohammadi: You cannot "summon" Jun here, as the user has not posted any comment or answer in this thread. My code is working for ANSI-encoded files.

Comment: Sorry, i know ur code is working but for me nothing happens, i tried a lot with ur code. And i just summon him because he wrote the script, i thought he might have a better solution.

Comment: The main issue (I doubt Jun can help it) is that the Notepad wrapper `open` method does not allow a Unicode string as an argument. You just can't do what you need with Notepad++. Either use Python, or other means, like Powershell, Perl, C#, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
import codecs
import os
import sys

filePathSrc="C:\\222\\3" # Path to the folder with files to convert
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(unicode(filePathSrc)):
    for fn in files: 
        if fn[-4:] == '.srt': # Specify type of the files
            filename = unicode(root + "\\" + fn)
            with codecs.open(filename,'r', encoding = "Windows-1251") as f:
                text = f.read()
                # process Unicode text
            with codecs.open(filename,'w',encoding='utf8') as f:
                # f.write(u'\uFEFF') # BOM mark optional
                f.write(text)
```

Points:

- `import codecs` added to work with files in Python
- `os.walk(unicode(filePathSrc))` is given a Unicode path to return Unicode file names
- You should specify the correct encoding for your files instead of `Windows-1251` in the `with codecs.open(filename,'r', encoding = "Windows-1251")` code.
- If the folder `filePathSrc` variable should have Unicode chars, convert them to `\uXXXX` notation (you can do that easily with [r12a Unicode Converter](http://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/) from the *JavaScript escapes* field). Say, your folder name is `7 Minutes 2014{جنایی}{7 دقیقه}`. You paste it to the green field, and click *Convert*. Then, grab the string from the JavaScript escapes field and use it for `filePathSrc` variable while also pre-pending the string with `u""` prefix. It will look as `filePathSrc=u"c:\\222\\7 Minutes 2014{\u062C\u0646\u0627\u06CC\u06CC}{7 \u062F\u0642\u06CC\u0642\u0647}"`. Then, instead of `os.walk(unicode(filePathSrc))` use `os.walk(filePathSrc)` since the string we pass is already Unicode.

Comment: Maybe because you do not have ANSI files in the first place. It works perfectly well on my end with ANSI encoded files with "Windows-1251" default system encoding for non-Unicode files. And by the way, "didn't worked" does not explain what is wrong with the code: does it throw exceptions, etc? Which version of PythonScript have you got?

Comment: i have but folder names are like this:
7 Minutes 2014{جنایی}{7 دقیقه}   @wiktor-stribiżew
and im using Python Script 1.0.8.0 Plugin in Notepad++, when i run your script nothing happens

Comment: Ok, I see. Here is the solution: 1) Convert the Arabic letters to the `\uXXXX` representation and add `u""` prefix (`filePathSrc=u"c:\\7 Minutes 2014{\u062C\u0646\u0627\u06CC\u06CC}{7 \u062F\u0642\u06CC\u0642\u0647}"`), 2) use `for root, dirs, files in os.walk(filePathSrc):`.

Comment: The first sample script that i posted did encode three hundred .srt files in folders and subfolders in the specific path which contained folders with diffrent names. it encoded them perfectly but it didnt encode files in folders with unicode characters in their names like the example above, so somehow i needed the script to recognize these folders in general not just one folder or a specific folder, because if i just wanted to encode one file why using a script? I appreciate ur help but it wasnt what i wanted. @wiktor-stribiżew

Comment: You need to provide the *starting* folder like this, with the special codes. Those that Python fetches should be Unicode already. Also, a script like this can't guess encoding of a file, you should only feed ANSI to it.

Comment: The starting folder doesnt have any unicode characters in name. Some of subfolders have @wiktor-stribiżew

Comment: I will attach a zip file to post containing sample folders to show what i mean, ok? @wiktor-stribiżew

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Unicode path in `os.walk()` it will return Unicode paths and filenames.  Notepad isn't required to convert the files.  Below is code that will work in Python 2 and Python 3 since it wasn't specified.

Note that strings are Unicode by default in Python 3, but the `from __future__` makes Python 2 strings default Unicode where normally they are byte strings.  Making sure you use Unicode strings everywhere is important.

`io.open` is the Python 3 version of `open`, but is available in Python 2 as well.  It opens files with "ANSI" encoding by default.  `locale.getpreferredencoding()` can be used to determine the exact encoding.  It is `cp1252` on US Windows.  `read()` will return the file data decoded into Unicode.

The encoding `utf-8-sig` will prepend a UTF-8-encoded BOM character (which Windows tends to like) and encode the written data using UTF-8.  If the BOM is not desired, use `utf8` instead.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import os
import io
import fnmatch
filePathSrc = r'C:\test'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(filePathSrc):
    for fn in fnmatch.filter(files,'*.srt'):
        fullname = os.path.join(root,fn)
        with io.open(fullname) as f:
            data = f.read()
        with io.open(fullname,'w',encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
            f.write(data)
```

Comment: hey it worked perfectly man, thanks. im so grateful. but if i want to change the encoding to ansi what do i do? i changed the encoding from script but it didnt worked. @mark-tolonen

Comment: @farhadmohammadi ANSI isn't an encoding. It's what Microsoft calls the default encoding for the localized version of Windows.  `io.open` defaults to that, not specifying the encoding gives you the ANSI default on Windows.

Comment: OK, but i run the script and it ruins the words.
ex: text before running script: بهشون ميگي که اصن باجه
text after running the script: ظ…ط¨ط§ط±ع©ظ‡
i used both 'utf-8-sig' & 'utf8', i cant figure out where is the problem.

Comment: @farhadmohammadi The original text was not the default ANSI encoding.  You do have to use the correct encoding when reading the file. There is a `chardet` module that can guess.  What localized version of Windows are you using?  What app did you use to read the original text?

Comment: The original text is the default ANSI encoding indeed. And i use windows 7 ultimate. Windows Notepad. @mark-tolonen

Comment: I will attach a zip file to my post, with some files and folders to show you what you are dealing with @mark-tolonen

Comment: For "localized", I mean US Windows, Persian Windows, etc.  Each has a different encoding used for "ANSI".  Windows Notepad on US Windows can't write  بهشون ميگي که اصن باجه in "ANSI", because the encoding for ANSI is [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).  That doesn't support Persian.

Comment: oh, so its US windows and i know windows notepad cannot write persian characters but if you change the System Locale into Persian, it will write these characters in ANSI.

Comment: It's not ANSI it's the encoding for the Persian locale which is probably `Windows-1256`. `locale.getpreferredencoding()` will tell you.   But if it save enough locale, I'll open should encoder properly. The garbage you posted looks more like it was UTF-8 but read As Windows-1256 and then decoded as UTF-8.

Comment: Where's that zip file?